# onscroll function for div won't work with getBoundingClientRect() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented an onscroll function for a div that worked like this:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  document.getElementById("faceExtractor").style.top = (($(window).scrollTop()) + 50) + "px";
};
```

That worked fine. Now I made the div element also draggable, which means after someone dragged the div a but down and then scrolled the div was put again 50px below the top of the page due to the onscroll function. I wanted to solve that, so that the div keeps it position while scrolling even when someone drageed it a a specific position and I tried this:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  topDistance = document.getElementById("faceExtractor").getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (topDistance < 50){
    document.getElementById("faceExtractor").style.top = (($(window).scrollTop()) + 50) + "px";
  } else {
    var gap = ($(window).scrollTop()) + topDistance;
    document.getElementById("faceExtractor").style.top = gap + "px";
  }  
};
```

But then the onscroll doesn't work at all. How can I modify my onscroll so that the div keeps it position and is not always put to the top of the page or a static position?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  positionFromTop = document.getElementById("faceExtractor").offsetTop;
  topDistance = document.body.parentElement.scrollTop+positionFromTop;
  if (topDistance < 50){
    document.getElementById("faceExtractor").style.top = topDistance+ "px";
  } else {
    var gap = topDistance;
    document.getElementById("faceExtractor").style.top = gap + "px";
  }  
};
```

Try this method. And, give 'position:absolute' for 'faceExtractor' Div.

Comment: I tried, it at least does something now, but now the div "runs" to the bottom of the page when scrolling and disappears.